# DMSDK QueryBatch how to check list of uri exists in marklogic

Tags: marklogic-9

I'm using Marklogic 9.0-8 on windows 10. from java code, I want to check a list of uris if these uris exists in marklogic, either xml document or binary mode.
I'm trying to use java client API with DMSDK, with QueryBatch. But I'm not sure wht to do with method onUrisReady. 
I was thinking to register ExportListener, but I don't want to return the whole document, I only want to know if the document exists in marklogic or not.

Can anyone give me some suggestion how to check if uri exists in marklogic without pulling all the documents out to client?

Thanks, Helen

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the examples in the [QueryBatcher](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/datamovement/QueryBatcher.html) documentation.  Might be useful.

Comment: I have list of known uris, I want to know if they exist in marklogic. using Querybatcher.onUrisReady(new ExportListener().onDocumentReady()), I also created transform lib for ExportListener to call so it doesn't return the whole document. Based on my test, I found if document exists in marklogic, I receive transform result back to java,; but if documents not exist, I receive nothing, no result, no error, it is just like skipped.   I prefer  there is some way to tell me  for sure if document not eixsts in marklogic.